# Why won't my main recognize what I returned?

Tags: java, methods, return

I can't get my program to recognize eClassGpa and sClassGpa even though I returned them in their methods. I am trying to add all of the GPA's in the main with the ones in the separate methods. When I do so the two things I returned create errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GPA3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to the GPA Calculator.");

        int Math;
        double mathGpa = 0;

        System.out.println("Math = ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Math= input.nextInt();

        if (Math >100){
            System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
        }
        if (Math >= 94){
            System.out.println("You have an A");
            mathGpa = 4.0;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 94 && Math >=90){
            System.out.println("You have an A-");
            mathGpa = 3.7;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 90 && Math >=87){
            System.out.println("You have a B+");
            mathGpa = 3.3;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 87 && Math >=80){
            System.out.println("You have a B");
            mathGpa = 3.0;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 80 && Math >=77){
            System.out.println("You have a B-");
            mathGpa = 2.7;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 77 && Math >=73){
            System.out.println("You have a C+");
            mathGpa = 2.3;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 73 && Math >=70){
            System.out.println("You have a C");
            mathGpa = 2.0;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 70 && Math >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a C-");
            mathGpa = 1.7;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 67 && Math >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a D+");
            mathGpa = 1.3;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 67 && Math >=63){
            System.out.println("You have a D");
            mathGpa = 1.0;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 63 && Math >=60){
            System.out.println("You have a D-");
            mathGpa = 0.7;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }
        if (Math < 60){
            System.out.println("You have a F");
            mathGpa = 0.0;
            System.out.println(mathGpa);
        }//End of Math

        int English;
        double englishGpa = 0;
        System.out.println("English = ");
        English= input.nextInt();

        if (English >100){
            System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
        }
        if (English >= 94 && English <101){
            System.out.println("You have an A");
            englishGpa = 4.0;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 94 && English >=90){
            System.out.println("You have an A-");
            englishGpa = 3.7;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 90 && English >=87){
            System.out.println("You have a B+");
            englishGpa = 3.3;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 87 && English >=80){
            System.out.println("You have a B");
            englishGpa = 3.0;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 80 && English >=77){
            System.out.println("You have a B-");
            englishGpa = 2.7;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 77 && English >=73){
            System.out.println("You have a C+");
            englishGpa = 2.3;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 73 && English >=70){
            System.out.println("You have a C");
            englishGpa = 2.0;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 70 && English >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a C-");
            englishGpa = 1.7;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 67 && English >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a D+");
            englishGpa = 1.3;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 67 && English >=63){
            System.out.println("You have a D");
            englishGpa = 1.0;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 63 && English >=60){
            System.out.println("You have a D-");
            englishGpa = 0.7;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }
        if (English < 60){
            System.out.println("You have a F");
            englishGpa = 0.0;
            System.out.println(englishGpa);
        }//End of English

        int Science;
        double SciGpa = 0;
        System.out.println("Science = ");
        Science= input.nextInt();

        if (Science >100){
            System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
        }
        if (Science >= 94 && Science <101){
            System.out.println("You have an A");
            SciGpa = 4.0;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 94 && Science >=90){
            System.out.println("You have an A-");
            SciGpa = 3.7;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 90 && Science >=87){
            System.out.println("You have a B+");
            SciGpa = 3.3;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 87 && Science >=80){
            System.out.println("You have a B");
            SciGpa = 3.0;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 80 && Science >=77){
            System.out.println("You have a B-");
            SciGpa = 2.7;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 77 && Science >=73){
            System.out.println("You have a C+");
            SciGpa = 2.3;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 73 && Science >=70){
            System.out.println("You have a C");
            SciGpa = 2.0;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 70 && Science >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a C-");
            SciGpa = 1.7;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 67 && Science >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a D+");
            SciGpa = 1.3;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 67 && Science >=63){
            System.out.println("You have a D");
            SciGpa = 1.0;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 63 && Science >=60){
            System.out.println("You have a D-");
            SciGpa = 0.7;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }
        if (Science < 60){
            System.out.println("You have a F");
            SciGpa = 0.0;
            System.out.println(SciGpa);
        }//End of Science

        int Spanish;
        double SpanGpa = 0;
        System.out.println("Spanish = ");
        Spanish= input.nextInt();

        if (Spanish >100){
            System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
        }
        if (Spanish >= 94 && Spanish <101){
            System.out.println("You have an A");
            SpanGpa = 4.0;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 94 && Spanish >=90){
            System.out.println("You have an A-");
            SpanGpa = 3.7;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 90 && Spanish >=87){
            System.out.println("You have a B+");
            SpanGpa = 3.3;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 87 && Spanish >=80){
            System.out.println("You have a B");
            SpanGpa = 3.0;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 80 && Spanish >=77){
            System.out.println("You have a B-");
            SpanGpa = 2.7;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 77 && Spanish >=73){
            System.out.println("You have a C+");
            SpanGpa = 2.3;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 73 && Spanish >=70){
            System.out.println("You have a C");
            SpanGpa = 2.0;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 70 && Spanish >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a C-");
            SpanGpa = 1.7;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 67 && Spanish >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a D+");
            SpanGpa = 1.3;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 67 && Spanish >=63){
            System.out.println("You have a D");
            SpanGpa = 1.0;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 63 && Spanish >=60){
            System.out.println("You have a D-");
            SpanGpa = 0.7;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }
        if (Spanish < 60){
            System.out.println("You have a F");
            SpanGpa = 0.0;
            System.out.println(SpanGpa);
        }//End of Spanish

        int Religion;
        double RGpa = 0;
        System.out.println("Religion = ");
        Religion= input.nextInt();

        if (Religion >100){
            System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
        }
        if (Religion >= 94 && Religion < 101){
            System.out.println("You have an A");
            RGpa = 4.0;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 94 && Religion >=90){
            System.out.println("You have an A-");
            RGpa = 3.7;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 90 && Religion >=87){
            System.out.println("You have a B+");
            RGpa = 3.3;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 87 && Religion >=80){
            System.out.println("You have a B");
            RGpa = 3.0;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 80 && Religion >=77){
            System.out.println("You have a B-");
            RGpa = 2.7;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 77 && Religion >=73){
            System.out.println("You have a C+");
            RGpa = 2.3;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 73 && Religion >=70){
            System.out.println("You have a C");
            RGpa = 2.0;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 70 && Religion >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a C-");
            RGpa = 1.7;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 67 && Religion >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a D+");
            RGpa = 1.3;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 67 && Religion >=63){
            System.out.println("You have a D");
            RGpa = 1.0;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 63 && Religion >=60){
            System.out.println("You have a D-");
            RGpa = 0.7;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }
        if (Religion < 60){
            System.out.println("You have a F");
            RGpa = 0.0;
            System.out.println(RGpa);
        }//End of Religion 
        answer(input);
        elective(input);

        double finalGrade;
        finalGrade= mathGpa + englishGpa+ SciGpa+ sClassGpa + eClassGpa;


    }//End of Main

    public static double answer(Scanner input)
        {//Begin answer
        double sClassGpa=0;
        System.out.println("Do you have gym this semester?");
        input.nextLine();
        String yes = "yes";
        String no = "no";
        String answer = input.nextLine();

        if (answer.equals(yes)){
            int Gym;
            System.out.println("Gym = ");
            Gym= input.nextInt();
            if (Gym >100){
                System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
            }
            if (Gym >= 94 && Gym < 101){
                System.out.println("You have an A");
                sClassGpa = 4.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 94 && Gym >=90){
                System.out.println("You have an A-");
                sClassGpa = 3.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 90 && Gym >=87){
                System.out.println("You have a B+");
                sClassGpa = 3.3;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 87 && Gym >=80){
                System.out.println("You have a B");
                sClassGpa = 3.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 80 && Gym >=77){
                System.out.println("You have a B-");
                sClassGpa = 2.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 77 && Gym >=73){
                System.out.println("You have a C+");
                sClassGpa = 2.3;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 73 && Gym >=70){
                System.out.println("You have a C");
                sClassGpa = 2.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 70 && Gym >=67){
                System.out.println("You have a C-");
                sClassGpa = 1.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 67 && Gym >=67){
                System.out.println("You have a D+");
                sClassGpa = 1.3;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 67 && Gym >=63){
                System.out.println("You have a D");
                sClassGpa = 1.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 63 && Gym >=60){
                System.out.println("You have a D-");
                sClassGpa = 0.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (Gym < 60){
                System.out.println("You have a F");
                sClassGpa = 0.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
        }//End Gym

        if (answer.equals(no)){
            int History;
            System.out.println("History = ");
            History= input.nextInt();

            if (History >100){
                System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
            }
            if (History >= 94 && History <101){
                System.out.println("You have an A");
                sClassGpa = 4.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 94 && History >=90){
                System.out.println("You have an A-");
                sClassGpa = 3.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 90 && History >=87){
                System.out.println("You have a B+");
                sClassGpa = 3.3;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 87 && History >=80){
                System.out.println("You have a B");
                sClassGpa = 3.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 80 && History >=77){
                System.out.println("You have a B-");
                sClassGpa = 2.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 77 && History >=73){
                System.out.println("You have a C+");
                sClassGpa = 2.3;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 73 && History >=70){
                System.out.println("You have a C");
                sClassGpa = 2.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 70 && History >=67){
                System.out.println("You have a C-");
                sClassGpa = 1.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 67 && History >=67){
                System.out.println("You have a D+");
                sClassGpa = 1.3;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 67 && History >=63){
                System.out.println("You have a D");
                sClassGpa = 1.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 63 && History >=60){
                System.out.println("You have a D-");
                sClassGpa = 0.7;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }
            if (History < 60){
                System.out.println("You have a F");
                sClassGpa = 0.0;
                System.out.println(sClassGpa);
            }//End of History
        }

        return (sClassGpa);
    }//End answer

    public static double elective(Scanner input)
    {//Begin answer
    double eClassGpa=0;
    System.out.println("Do you have one or two electives this year?");
    System.out.println("Hint: write answers in word form");
    input.nextLine();
    String one = "one";
    String two = "two";
    String elective = input.nextLine();

    if (elective.equals(one)){
        int electiveOne;
        System.out.println("Elective 1 = ");
        electiveOne= input.nextInt();
        if (electiveOne >100){
            System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
        }
        if (electiveOne >= 94 && electiveOne < 101){
            System.out.println("You have an A");
            eClassGpa = 4.0;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 94 && electiveOne >=90){
            System.out.println("You have an A-");
            eClassGpa = 3.7;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 90 && electiveOne >=87){
            System.out.println("You have a B+");
            eClassGpa = 3.3;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 87 && electiveOne >=80){
            System.out.println("You have a B");
            eClassGpa = 3.0;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 80 && electiveOne >=77){
            System.out.println("You have a B-");
            eClassGpa = 2.7;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 77 && electiveOne >=73){
            System.out.println("You have a C+");
            eClassGpa = 2.3;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 73 && electiveOne >=70){
            System.out.println("You have a C");
            eClassGpa = 2.0;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 70 && electiveOne >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a C-");
            eClassGpa = 1.7;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 67 && electiveOne >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a D+");
            eClassGpa = 1.3;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 67 && electiveOne >=63){
            System.out.println("You have a D");
            eClassGpa = 1.0;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 63 && electiveOne >=60){
            System.out.println("You have a D-");
            eClassGpa = 0.7;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }
        if (electiveOne < 60){
            System.out.println("You have a F");
            eClassGpa = 0.0;
            System.out.println(eClassGpa);
        }


    }//End Elective 1

    if(elective.equals(two)){

        double e1ClassGpa=0;
        double e2ClassGpa=0;

        if (elective.equals(two)){
            int electiveOne;
            System.out.println("Elective 1 = ");
            electiveOne= input.nextInt();
            if (electiveOne >100){
                System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
            }
            if (electiveOne >= 94 && electiveOne < 101){
                System.out.println("You have an A");
                e1ClassGpa = 4.0;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 94 && electiveOne >=90){
                System.out.println("You have an A-");
                e1ClassGpa = 3.7;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 90 && electiveOne >=87){
                System.out.println("You have a B+");
                e1ClassGpa = 3.3;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 87 && electiveOne >=80){
                System.out.println("You have a B");
                e1ClassGpa = 3.0;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 80 && electiveOne >=77){
                System.out.println("You have a B-");
                e1ClassGpa = 2.7;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 77 && electiveOne >=73){
                System.out.println("You have a C+");
                e1ClassGpa = 2.3;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 73 && electiveOne >=70){
                System.out.println("You have a C");
                e1ClassGpa = 2.0;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 70 && electiveOne >=67){
                System.out.println("You have a C-");
                e1ClassGpa = 1.7;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 67 && electiveOne >=67){
                System.out.println("You have a D+");
                e1ClassGpa = 1.3;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 67 && electiveOne >=63){
                System.out.println("You have a D");
                e1ClassGpa = 1.0;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 63 && electiveOne >=60){
                System.out.println("You have a D-");
                e1ClassGpa = 0.7;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }
            if (electiveOne < 60){
                System.out.println("You have a F");
                e1ClassGpa = 0.0;
                System.out.println(e1ClassGpa);
            }

        }//End Elective 1

        int elective2;
        System.out.println("Elective 2 = ");
        elective2= input.nextInt();

        if (elective2 >100){
            System.out.println("You have mistyped something");
        }
        if (elective2 >= 94 && elective2 <101){
            System.out.println("You have an A");
            e2ClassGpa = 4.0;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 94 && elective2 >=90){
            System.out.println("You have an A-");
            e2ClassGpa = 3.7;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 90 && elective2 >=87){
            System.out.println("You have a B+");
            e2ClassGpa = 3.3;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 87 && elective2 >=80){
            System.out.println("You have a B");
            e2ClassGpa = 3.0;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 80 && elective2 >=77){
            System.out.println("You have a B-");
            e2ClassGpa = 2.7;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 77 && elective2 >=73){
            System.out.println("You have a C+");
            e2ClassGpa = 2.3;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 73 && elective2 >=70){
            System.out.println("You have a C");
            e2ClassGpa = 2.0;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 70 && elective2 >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a C-");
            e2ClassGpa = 1.7;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 67 && elective2 >=67){
            System.out.println("You have a D+");
            e2ClassGpa = 1.3;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 67 && elective2 >=63){
            System.out.println("You have a D");
            e2ClassGpa = 1.0;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 63 && elective2 >=60){
            System.out.println("You have a D-");
            e2ClassGpa = 0.7;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }
        if (elective2 < 60){
            System.out.println("You have a F");
            e2ClassGpa = 0.0;
            System.out.println(e2ClassGpa);
        }//End of Elective 2
        eClassGpa= e1ClassGpa + e2ClassGpa;
        }//End of ElectiveTwo
    input.close();
    return (eClassGpa);
    }//End of Elective

}//End of Class
```

Comment: It looks like sClassGpa and eClassGpa are being used in main() but they are never declared or allocated anywhere.

Comment: Just to be clear, what are the sClassGpa and eClassGpa?

Comment: sClassGpa and eClassGpa are allocated as local variables in their respective functions but you are expecting them to be class variables.  Move them out to the class level and they will become visible within your class.   Note that they still won't be visible to main as you've never instantiated `GPA3`

Comment: Also, naming methods and variables within those methods with the same value is (at best) going to confuse everybody and typically not work at all.  This is not VB6.

Answer (score 0):

You call the methods `elective` and `answer` without storing the result into a variable.

You should use a variable to store the results:

```
sClassGpa= answer(input);
eClassGpa = elective(input);
```

You should realize that the local variables you created inside the functions, although they have the same name are not the same as the ones you declared in the main function.  That is why you have to store the result of your functions in a variable if you want to use them.

**Edit**

To be clear: You should put those lines towards the end of your main method

```
        }//End of Religion 
        answer(input);   //Edit this line...
        elective(input); //And this line

        double finalGrade;
        finalGrade= mathGpa + englishGpa+ SciGpa+ sClassGpa + eClassGpa;   
}//End of Main
```

Answer (score 0):

To put @MiltoxBeyond's answer into context:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    // your main method
    // End of Religion

    double sClassGpa = answer(input);
    double eClassGpa = elective(input);

    double finalGrade = mathGpa + englishGpa+ SciGpa+ sClassGpa + eClassGpa;
}
```